# how to remove <optional> from Soap request

Tags: wcf, soapui, datacontract, messagecontract

I am using SoapUI Pro 4.6.1 for testing my WCF service.
And my request look like this

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:tem="http://tempuri.org/">
       <soapenv:Header/>
    <soapenv:Body>
  <tem:doPaymentRequest>
     <!--Optional:-->
     <tem:credentials>
        <!--Optional:-->
        <tem:accountId>?</tem:accountId>
        <!--Optional:-->
        <tem:userName>?</tem:userName>
        <!--Optional:-->
        <tem:password>?</tem:password>
     </tem:credentials>
     </tem:doPaymentRequest>
```

How to remove  --Optional:--> from SOAP
I am using message format to wrap my data contract and i am using isRequired attribute for DataContract.

Answer (score 4):

Do you want to remove any oprional element? Then File -> Preferences -> WSDL Settings -> Include Optional (this is a checkbox). When you add request to your test case it also suggests to select option "Create optional elements".

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify `[DataMember(IsRequired = true)]` on all of the properties in the data contract class, then they won't be optional.

Comment: yes,its true if we are using only DataContract and DataMember.But when we use a MessageContract to wrap the DataContract,this doesnt work.

Answer (score 0):

```
[DataContract]
public class GetColorsRS
{
    DataMember(Name = "Errors", Order = 1, IsRequired=false)]
    public List<Error> Errors { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: yes,its true if we are using only DataContract and DataMember.But when we use a MessageContract to wrap the DataContract,this doesnt work.